# Mocking a String-class method in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, mocking, swift2

I've got some Swift 2.0 code, for which I'm trying to achieve 100% code coverage. I'm doing some JSON handling, part of which looks like so:

```
guard let jsonData = jsonText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
    throw ErrorCode.JSONEncodingFailure
}
```

I don't think there's a real-world case in which any string can't be encoded as UTF-8, but I don't want to open myself up to a crashing error either, so that code must remain. How can I mock the `jsonText` object to return nil for `dataUsingEncoding()`?

The closest I've come is to subclass NSString like so:

```
public class BadString: NSString {

    public override var length: Int {
        get {
            return 5
        }
    }

    public override func characterAtIndex(index: Int) -> unichar {
        return  0
    }

    public override func dataUsingEncoding(encoding: NSStringEncoding) -> NSData? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Here's the problem, though. In order for my mock implementation to be used, I have to define `jsonText` (a function parameter) as an `NSString`, rather than `String`, which feels wrong for an all-Swift codebase. With it defined as a Swift `String`, I have to cast my `BadString` to that type, and it uses the `String` implementation instead of my own.

Is there another (clean) way to achieve this?

Comment: So you want the method to return nil every time so that an error gets thrown every time? If that's the case: Why would you do that??

Comment: @Kametrixom As explained, I want to hit that case in my unit tests, to verify the proper error code is returned. This isn't intended for production code, just tests.

Answer (score 1):

You will be hard-pressed to find a string that cannot be encoded using UTF-8! As long as you know that is the encoding you will be using, I would suggest that you not worry about testing the "encoding failure" case.

However, if you still desire to test it then I recommend making one of the following changes in order to allow you to do so:

(1) change the way you are thinking about the 'failure': if you know that the string you are encoding will always be non-empty, then broaden the `guard` to also require that the encoded data has length > 0, e.g. =>

```
guard let jsonData = jsonText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        where jsonData.length > 0 else {
    throw ErrorCode.JSONEncodingFailure
}
```

...using this idea, you can now use an empty string for `jsonText` and trigger this code path (assuming that an empty string would also satisfy your definition of 'failure' here)

(2) store your string encoding value in a variable (let's call it `stringEncoding`) that you can access during your test setup, and then test this using incompatible values for `jsonText` and `stringEncoding`, e.g. =>

```
var jsonText = ""
let stringEncoding = NSASCIIStringEncoding
```

...I guarantee that `jsonText.dataUsingEncoding(stringEncoding)` will return `nil` in this case  :)

Happy Testing! I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, those are a couple valid approaches. I'm still interested to find out about mocking methods on `Swift.String`

Comment: it's an interesting question - as a value type I wouldn't ordinarily consider mocking `String`, but with the bridging to `NSString`... I'll have to think more about this today  :)

Comment: Did any ideas end up striking you?

Comment: This answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45686921](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45686921) was helpful, though it seemed to indicate you can't override methods in String because it's a struct, unlike NSString, which is a class. Tried for about 4 hours but couldn't override the built-in String methods for mocking, unfortunately.