# Convenience initializer on NSString in swift

Tags: swift

When I try to create a Convenience initializer on NSString in swift it fails with

> error: cannot assign to value: 'self' is immutable
>       self = "(number)"

```
extension NSString {
  public init(for number: Int) {
    self = "\(number)"
  }
}
```

While a similar extension on String works

```
extension String {
  public init(for number: Int) {
    self = "\(number)"
  }
}
```

Comment: I've revised my answer with working code. Please read.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `NSString` in Swift? By the way the naming convention is `init(number` to be able to expose the syntax to ObjC as `initWithNumber`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSString` is a *class* (a reference type) and `String` is a *struct*
(a value type), and these have different rules for initialization.

Value types (`struct` and `enum`) do not support inheritance and have
simpler initialization rules. In particular, you can initialize a 
value by assigning to `self`:

```
extension String {
    public init(for number: Int) {
        self = "\(number)"
    }
}
```

Class initialization is a two-phase process in order to prevent
property values from being accessed before they are initialized.
It  must follow certain rules, and one of them is
that a convenience initializer must delegate to another initializer
of the same type (and ultimately to a designated initializer):

```
extension NSString {
    public convenience init(for number: Int) {
        self.init(string: "\(number)")
    }
}
```

Contrary to Objective-C, Swift does not (yet?) support "factory initialization", where you can create and return an instance of 
the class or some subclass, instead of initiliazing `self`.

For details, see [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) in "The Swift Programming Language" reference.

Answer (score -1):

`NSString` is an immutable type, meaning that you cannot change it. It is throwing the error because you are setting itself. However, the `String` type is mutable, so it doesn't throw an error.

Try this instead.

```
extension NSString {
  public convenience init(for number: Int) {
    self.init(string: "\(number)")
  }
}
```

[Working code in Swift Sandbox](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5992733c3bbec6611ebed47e)

Comment: String and NSString are both immutable.